# android - Why is ImageView canvas black?

Tags: android, canvas, imageview

I'm new to android graphic so hold on to your hats!
The screen is black whatever i do. 
I draw a circle and i draw bitmap and noting shows.
Here is xml,code and a picture showing my screen.
Im thinking i have to set the size of the ImageView maybe that's why it's black??!

R.layout.main1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.hasse.move.DrawView 
    android:id="@+id/mainView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"

  />
   <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
   <EditText 
    android:id="@+id/edittextaddtext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnsave"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="wrap"
   />
   <Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnsave" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="save"
   />
   </RelativeLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

DrawView class

```
public class DrawView extends ImageView {
private Context ctx;
public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet atts) {
    super(context, atts);
    this.ctx = context;
} 
@Override 
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/PTPPservice/163693fe-7c48-4568-a082-00047123b9f1.2.IMAG2200.jpg";
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 2;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath,options);     

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 10,10, null);
    canvas.drawCircle(10,10,10,null);
}
```

}

main Activity

```
public class Main extends Activity {

DrawView theImage;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // draw the view
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);

    theImage = (DrawView) findViewById(R.id.mainView);
    //do stuff
}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
//  Toast.makeText(this, "onConfigurationChanged",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}

Image

[image]

Comment: Two comments: 1) your background color is 0x00FF00, which means that *alpha*, the opaqueness, is zero.  If you want the background to be green, set the background color to 0xFF00FF00.

Comment: I kind of got it working like this. In constructor im running ...setImageBitmap(btm). And in the onDraw im running ...canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0,0, null);. This is strange but it seems i must run that line in constructor kind of like initiating the imageView(dunno). but i have two images, one is centered middle and one is positioned 0,0 Andy ide?

Comment: 2) It's an ImageView, not a Canvas.  I just bring it up because I thought you literally meant canvas and started to answer with that in mind, until I saw that it wasn't.

Comment: yea ok sorry , but i draw on the canvas of the imageView. I update the question head!

Comment: Thanks all! Got it working will post answer tomorrow.
Got a new follow up question here [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971268/android-how-to-set-image-in-imageview-to-right-proportions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, your unlikely to see the circle as your trying to draw it with a null paint object. To test your code make sure you use a Paint object with a colour that contrasts the background colour. Secondly, I would call the super object method e.g.

```
super.onDraw(canvas);
```

I'm not 100% sure about drawing the bitmap with a null Paint object.
Also, check the package name of your DrawView class (com.hasse.move.DrawView) in your layout file matches that of the actual DrawView class.

Comment: Thanks Im adding super.onDraw(canvas);