# android - How to set image in ImageView to right proportions

Tags: android, imageview

Look at the picture below.
I'm loading an image from sdcard with code belove.

I cannot get the picture to automatically fill the ImageView. I set the background to color green only to highlight the problem. I have tried many android:ScaleType like CENTER and FIT_XY but.

Im now using inSampleSize = 8  but how can the ImageView automatically scale the image to be in the right hight/width proportions and fill the screen

Also another thing, You see the ExitText and Button is placed above the Imageview(I think).
I want them to be under and not block the ImageView. Maybe i misunderstand the android layout technical.

[image]

DrawView.java

```
public class DrawView extends ImageView {

private Context ctx;
public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet atts) {
    super(context, atts);
    this.ctx = context;
} 
@Override 
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/PTPPservice/163693fe-7c48-4568-a082-00047123b9f1.2.IMAG2200.jpg";
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 8;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath,options);     

    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rect,null);
}
```

}

Main1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.hasse.move.DrawView 
    android:id="@+id/mainView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
  />
   <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
   <EditText 
    android:id="@+id/edittextaddtext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnsave"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="wrap"
   />
   <Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnsave" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="save"
   />
   </RelativeLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Main Activity

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    DrawView theImage;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // draw the view
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);

        theImage = (DrawView) findViewById(R.id.mainView);
        //do stuff
    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
    //  Toast.makeText(this, "onConfigurationChanged",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are using the destination rectangle to be the size of the loaded bitmap instead of the full size of canvas: `Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());`

You need to find out the size of your canvas. For that you can use onSizeChanged:

```
@Override
public void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){
  super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

  screenW = w;
  screenH = h;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Lumis It worked. The image is perfect but in landscape mood it's stretched. Guess i have to do some calculation but is this really so hard to set a Bitmap. I know the Android.gallery and imageSwitcher They display so easy any picture in all moods

Comment: This is because you draw on canvas, hence you need to calculate yourself the size of your destination rectangle in accordance with the ratio of the image as well its positioning. If you get the formula right then it will resize properly on orientation change.